# GCC compiling error: conflicts with the other architecture options, which specify a mips1 processor

Tags: gcc, makefile, embedded, valgrind

Im trying to cross-compile valgrind for MIPS architecture but im getting errors.

```
$ make


make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/valgrind-3.9.0'
Making all in include
make[2]: Entering directory `/valgrind-3.9.0/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/valgrind-3.9.0/include'
Making all in VEX
make[2]: Entering directory `/valgrind-3.9.0/VEX'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/valgrind-3.9.0/VEX'
/toolchain/rsdk-1.5.6-5281-EB-2.6.30-0.9.30.3-110915/bin/rsdk-linux-gcc -    DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I.. -I../include -I../VEX/pub -DVGA_mips32=1 -DVGO_linux=1 -DVGP_mips32_linux=1 -DVGPV_mips32_linux_vanilla=1 -Ipriv  -O2 -g -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-format-zero-length -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin -mips32 -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -fstrict-aliasing -Wno-long-long  -Wwrite-strings -fno-stack-protector -MT priv/libvex_mips32_linux_a-main_globals.o -MD -MP -MF priv/.deps/libvex_mips32_linux_a-main_globals.Tpo -c -o priv/libvex_mips32_linux_a-main_globals.o `test -f     'priv/main_globals.c' || echo './'`priv/main_globals.c
priv/main_globals.c:1: error: '-mips32' conflicts with the other architecture options,     which specify a mips1 processor
make[3]: *** [priv/libvex_mips32_linux_a-main_globals.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/valgrind-3.9.0/VEX'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/valgrind-3.9.0/VEX'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/valgrind-3.9.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I dont know if there is a problem with -mips32 argument but if i remove it i get error with 'opcodes not supported' later. Im not sure if this error complains about incompability issue.

Comment: I'll say up-front that I've spent a little time in the past trying to do this kind of thing for valgrind and found it almost impossible.  It's not relocatable, and it's very hard to cross-compile.  I've found that building it natively on each platform is far and away the simplest, if you can.  Second, I'm assuming that `rsdk-linux-gcc` is a MIPS32 cross-compiler?  I've never heard of it.

Comment: I will see if i can build it natively using an storage device via usb in the embedded device. Rsdk-linux-gcc is the compiler of our OEM for his embedded MIPS32 architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I land up with the same issue and below is the solution. Change -march=mips32 to --march=mips32r2. I have used my build script something like -

```
if [[ "$PATH" == *"/usr/local/mips-2012.09/bin"* ]]; then
echo codesourcery toolchain path is already in PATH var
else
export PATH="/usr/local/mips-2012.09/bin:$PATH"
echo added codesourcery toolchain path to PATH var
fi

export AR=mips-linux-gnu-ar
export CC='mips-linux-gnu-gcc -EL'
export CXX='mips-linux-gnu-g++ -EL'
export LINK='mips-linux-gnu-g++ -EL'
export RANLIB=mips-linux-gnu-ranlib
export CFLAGS='-march=mips32r2'
export CCFLAGS='-march=mips32r2'
export CXXFLAGS='-march=mips32r2'
```

Happy Coding :-)